# Yii2 ... Yii3 ... or Laravel?

Tags: laravel, yii2

I’ve been using Yii since version 1 … I’ve done lots of projects (i’d say about 50). I know Yii.
But I am being disappointed.
Yii was glorious and wonderful in 2014-2017, but after 2018 I’m not seeing same activity.

Forums are useless, old, inactive … there’s not more Yii2 extensions or modules. Everything is “old”, unfinished, discontinued …

Now I’m facing changes in my life as coder, and I was wondering whether to wait for Yii3 (because it will be a revolution), or to switch to Laravel.

Sincerely… what do you think if this “Yii environment” situation ?

**Please, I would like comments from people who really know both environments, not only Laravel lovers.**

Can you anyone tell me a WORKING and UPDATED extension

- for social networks that works PERFECTLY ?
  yii2-usuario was the best … WAS … linkedin works sometimes, facebook are not updated, and there’s no newer social since 2016
- can you tell me other for datatables ?
  nullref has awful support since it’s everything rewritten in Javascript so you can’t access properly relations and subrelations of models
- for payments (stripe compatible for example) ?

for…
and so on…

These just last 3 examples has beautiful, crazy updated and reviewed plugins in Laravel, for example. Or even in NodeJS.

2amigos and kartiv were two perfect partners for Yii2 core … but they are not being continued … so they are pretty old

Anytime I search for any “extension” in github, all projects are 4 years ago (the newest!).

By the way … Yii3 started in 2019 … 60% done so far … and can’t be used yet for real working projects in live. So … waiting 2 years more with this so empty market of extensions ?

Let’s be clear, my problem with Yii is NOT the core (Thank you Sam and others for your infinite work!), but the community, extensions made (and/or updated) and “movement” of the ecosystem.

I know I can code myself (i’ve done lots of extensions), but it’s easy as a coder when you have good repositories with pretty new extensions and solutions, and a very active community behind. This forum has about 150 posts this year. Laravel (for example, 150 posts represents just the last 4 days). Have you notice tons of posts here with 0 replies ?

Also, Yii coders was easy to find in 2015 … now it’s 1 out of 100 maybe.

Let’s assume Yii environment has decreased drastically in the last 4 years.

Comment: Duplicate - same at https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/yii2-yii3-or-laravel/133919

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to move to laravel.

As yii and laravel uses almost similar behavior on basic level
MVC, Based on symphony, ORM

I honestly think you'll easily grap what laravel is offering.

Plus, laravel is upgrading day by day.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies in your question .
Big community, Wonderful documentation, Enjoyable coding, Lot of feature and package, Popularity and ... all of them can describe Laravel.

**Do not doubt and take a deep dive.**

Comment: I know the benefits of Laravel as such, but have you worked with Yii in the past ? I'd like comments of people who really know both environments...

Comment: No i am laravel developer and it definitely meets all my needs. you can test laravel environment in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

If you worked with Yii2, you should definitely use Yii3.
I'm using it for minor projects and I'm learning a lot.
The advantages are the same as always

- Very fast (surely faster than Laravel)
- Very complete
- Very customizable
- Very standard and modern (A bit difficult to start to understand it)

I recommend you to start with the [demo application](https://github.com/yiisoft/demo/) (it's a blog) or the [base application](https://github.com/yiisoft/app/) (blank)

Comment: The problem with Yii2 is that all libraries, all extensions are extremely OLD. Every github project based in Yii2 has last update 3 or 4 years ago. Nothing is new, reviewed or revised (I mean extensions). And I'm lack of really working extensions of social login (yii2-usuario was the best... "WAS" since it's deprecated), of datatables (nullref is the only one and it's very bad ...), and so on ...
I'm in love with Yii, but just the core ... there's no "extensions" or packs as Laravel community provides

Comment: @FlamingMoe, but mariovials tells about Yii3 - and he's right.

Answer (score 0):

What's with the packages?
That on Yii2 you can only use Yii2 - compatible packages? take any package and use it, use the dependency injection container.

If we talk about the fact that the framework is outdated, then yes there is such ...

I myself wrote more than a dozen projects on Yii2.
I didn't really like Larevel, my opinion.
But the symphony, on the contrary, I was very pleased with.